# WPF User Control - control property that defaults to another built-in property if not specified explicitly

Tags: c#, wpf

Given a simple user control made of two text blocks, they would inherit say the Foreground property from the control's parent. But if I wanted the control to be able to override the Foreground of the first text block only, I can add a dependency property on the control (FirstBlockForeground) and it will work fine if explicitly specified but I want it to be the value of whatever was the Foreground value for the user control if it wasn't specified.

```xml
<UserControl ..... x:Name="myCtrl">
   <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="First" Foreground={Binding FirstBlockForeground, ElementName=myCtrl}/>
     <TextBlock Text="Second"/>
   </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I.e. on the parent:

```xml
<local:myCtrl Foreground="red" FirstBlockForeground="blue"/>
```

works fine.

```xml
<local:myCtrl Foreground="red" />
```

FirstBlockForeground will have the default value (specified in the `DependencyProperty.Register` call) but I want it to be red.

Is it possible to avoid having to explicitly specify FirstBlockForeground every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UserControl could have a Style with a Setter for the FirstBlockForeground property, which binds to its Foreground:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyCtrl"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" ...>

    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:MyCtrl.FirstBlockForeground"
                    Value="{Binding Foreground,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="First"
                   Foreground="{Binding FirstBlockForeground,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Second"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply check if the `FirstBlockForeground` property has been set before the control is loaded:

```
public MyCtrl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (FirstBlockForeground == null)
        {
            FirstBlockForeground = Foreground;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think if you set `<UserControl.Style>` like this, then application-wide default style for MyCtrl won't work ( I mean `<Application.Resources><Style TragetType="{x:Type MyCtrl}"><Setter Property="FirstBlockForeground" Value="Red"/></Style>`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's true. The Setter may then of course be moved into that default Style.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens - The OnLoaded approach works. I tried this first myself but my mistake was to do it in the ctor (after InitComp) and the FirstForeground is not populated yet. Miss on my part not to try OnLoaded as well. I tried a trigger as well but a DataTrigger and it failed with 'Value' cannot be a Binding. Anyway - thanks again! This was driving me nuts...